# Are there any function in Mathematica that is similar to pcolor in Python

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a colormap with Mathematica.

My dataset has a 1D array of length A which provides x-axis values, and a 1D array of length B which provides y-axis values, and a 2D array of size A*B which provides the data I want to show in the colormap.

The x-axis values are monotonic but not equally spaced, and same for the y-axis values.

In Python, I can call the function pcolor([X, Y] C), where X and Y are the 1D arrays and C is the 2D array.

I wonder if there is any similar function in Mathematica. I did search in the documents but haven't found anything similar.

PS: I was using ArrayPlot and most of the things I want to do can be worked out. But I encountered several problems:

1. In Python, the ticks are set automatically. In Mathematica, since my x-axis values and y-axis values are not equally spaced, what I did was I picked every n-th values in the arrays and set them as the ticks, but very often they are numbers like 754.278, 756.432, and I want to show ticks like 754, 756, i.e., some integers.
2. I found the option "PlotRange" does not work correctly when I simultaneously use the option "DataReversed -> True", i.e., if I set "PlotRange -> {All,{760,780}}", the range of the plot will be "All" on x-axis but something like {736,753} on y-axis. (I will try to provide some code later)

Therefore, I am trying to find a function which works like pcolor. Any solutions to those problems are also very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should focus and abbreviate your question. At least provide a *TL;DR* version at the beginning. Also, please format your code. I would suggest that you start by taking the [tour] so you know what are the site and community expectations, and then [edit] your question based on what you have learned.

Comment: Also, it's better to add some data for us to play with, and a graphic showing the expected output. Anyway, if I understand the question correctly, why not `ListDensityPlot`?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for the suggestions! Yes, ListDensityPlot is the function I was looking for. I tried it out but it took a long time to plot a 1300*240 dataset. I guess I will use Python instead. But it is certainly good to know about this function!

Comment: If you don't need the graphic to be smooth, adding `InterpolationOrder->0` should save you some time. It's certainly possible to speed up further, but again, we need some data to play with.